Four Columns, Two Odd Connections
Here are four columns, each with the names (full or partial) of four people that have something in common:



Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D




Patrick Depailler
Syd
Knight
Michael Caine


Ricardo Rosset
Ralf
Rooney
Guy Pearce


Martin Brundle
Malcolm
Brady
Albert Finney


Brian Henton
Brian
Gretzky
Jim Carrey



These columns can be connected in two different ways:

Find each column's commonality. You will find that three of them share a commonality of their own, yet the fourth does not.
Find a name that matches all four commonalities and can go in all four columns. Again, you will find that one of them is slightly different.

What are the odd ones out among these two connections - and what do those odd ones out have in common?
